# copy-paste columns on excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Been trying to copy-paste columns on excel VBA for days, code doesn't work no matter what

```
Sub CopyRangeofCellsanotherone()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRowToCopy As Long

    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\trabalho da DELL\source.xlsx")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\trabalho da DELL\destination.xlsx")

    LastRowToCopy = x.Sheets("sourcesheet").Cells(x.Sheets("sourcesheet").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    x.Sheets("sourcesheet").Range("A" & LastRowToCopy).Copy 'copy from A1 to lastrow

    LastRow = y.Sheets("destsheet").Cells(y.Sheets("destsheet").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row

    y.Sheets("destsheet").Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial 'paste on the lastrow of destination + 1 (so next empty row)

    x.Close

End Sub
```

I think the code is mostly self-explanatory (or atleast, what I intend it to do) but it's not working!! How can I copy contents from column A - source sheet , to column A - destination sheet?
And how can I then apply that , to a set of columns? (from A to G for example).
I have under 5 hours of VBA under my belt so this might look really simple to some of you...
edit: forgot to mention it gives me run-time error 91 on LastRowToCopy line.

Comment: Is the name "sourcesheet" correct? Otherwise, to help discover the issue, break that line into two or three statements. Declare a Worksheet reference and point it at `x.Sheets("sourcesheet")` first. Do the same for destsheet.

Comment: (I have amended your topic title, it should be brief and descriptive.)

Comment: @AndyG just did the source sheet reference, it pasted one value on the bottom of my destination sheet, which made me realise what the problem might be: i have a finite table on my destination worksheet, instead of just ....cells. Is that what's causing the problem? Because the table isn't long enough for all the values on my source sheet.

Comment: I don't follow. You say the code now works, as it pastes, but suggest there is a problem. What is this new problem?

Comment: it doesn't "work" to the full extent of what it should do: it just pasted one single value of that column , on the bottom of the source sheet.

Comment: If you are trying to paste the full column-data then you need to construct the expression "A2:A200" where 200 is your LastRowToCopy. (This is one approach.)

Comment: Used last row variables like @QHarr did, worked wonders! Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below.

Notes on what you have written:

Extend this to fully reference a range not just one cell

```
 sourceSheet.Range("A1:A" & sourceLastRow)
```

Add + 1 here to paste to the next available row

```
destSheet.Range("A" & destLastRow + 1)
```

Set up variables for the sheet themselves so code is more readable

```
Set sourceSheet = sourceBk.Sheets("sourcesheet")
```

Include more of a description with the lastRow variable so you know which workbook and worksheet is being referenced

```
sourceLastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

And of course, have `Option Explicit` at the top to check your variable declarations.

Full code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRangeofCellsanotherone()

    Dim sourceBk As Workbook
    Dim destBK As Workbook
    Dim sourceLastRow As Long
    Dim destLastRow As Long
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet

    Set sourceBk = Workbooks.Open("C:\trabalho da DELL\source.xlsx")
    Set destBK = Workbooks.Open("C:\trabalho da DELL\destination.xlsx")

    Set sourceSheet = sourceBk.Sheets("sourcesheet")
    Set destSheet = destBK.Sheets("destsheet")

    sourceLastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    destLastRow = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row

    sourceSheet.Range("A1:A" & sourceLastRow).Copy 'copy from A1 to lastrow

    destSheet.Range("A" & destLastRow + 1).PasteSpecial 'paste on the lastrow of destination + 1 (so next empty row)

    sourceBk.Close

End Sub
```

Extending the copy range:

There are a variety of ways to extend this to a range of columns (you will need to explain this further).

For example, if you know in advance the last column e.g. "C", you can amend the line for sourceSheet range as follows:

```
sourceSheet.Range("A1:C" & sourceLastRow)
```

If you don't know you can find the last column e.g. as per [Ron De Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

```
 sourceLastCol =sourceSheet.Cells(1,sourceSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Syntax for copying source range would then change to

```
sourceSheet.Range(sourceSheet.Cells(1, 1), sourceSheet.Cells(sourceLastRow, sourceLastCol)).Copy
```

Comment: Thanks! Haven't tested yet but seems great! Forgot to ask, where can i make it so that it starts pasting on row 2 of the destination sheet, instead of row 1 ? I know i have to add something like StartRow = 2 or something but I forgot :/

Comment: Just tested, subscript out-of-range on set destsheet. I don't understand, it exists, it's not hidden, it has the same exact name "destsheet". Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: check for any white space characters ?

Comment: just literally created a new empty "destsheet", nothing ... I'm losing my mind over this ._.

Comment: Not sure most common issues are wrong workbook or sheet doesn't exist or sheet name has hidden/different characters. Was does ?Activesheet.Name give you in the immediate pane for the worksheet code window associated with destsheet

Comment: EDIT: IT WORKED! I saved everything, closed all excel processes, started everything from scratch with your code and it worked! NICE! Thank you so much

Comment: sorry to be troubling you with a trivial question, but if I want to copy this information to multiple destination sheets, i just need to declare all the dest sheets , and make use of my pasteSpecial line as many times as I need, correct?

Comment: You will also need to collect the lastRow of each destination sheet to ensure you are then pasting to the next available row (with +1) for each. This would start to lend itself to a loop where you have an array of worksheet names (are they in the same workbook?) and loop that array  to pick up the current worksheet name to paste to, find the last row in that sheet and paste to the lastRow + 1. Loop to next sheet.....

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub foo2()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\trabalho da DELL\source.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\trabalho da DELL\destination.xlsx")

y.Sheets("destsheet").Range("A:A").Value = x.Sheets("sourcesheet").Range("A:A").Value

x.Close

End Sub
```

Check if the above code copies column A successfully.
If it does, then repeat the line
y.Sheets("destsheet").Range("A:A").Value = x.Sheets("sourcesheet").Range("A:A").Value
replacing Column A with other columns.